# Rails: Testing Devise in RSpec Controllers, Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I'm writing tests for my Devise setup via controllers, I followed this guide to get the test helpers setup: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29 it seems to be correct as I have access to the `sign_in` helper successfully. But I cannot get `sign_out` to work at all. Here is the test in question:

```
describe InvitesController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    before :each do
      @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
      sign_in @admin
    end

    it 'has the index view' do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end

    it 'is not accesible to non-logged in users' do
      sign_out @admin
      get :index
      response.should_not be_success
    end
  end
...
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
...
end
```

I get following error:

```
Failures:

  1) InvitesController GET #index is not accesible to non-logged in users
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ArgumentError:
       uncaught throw :warden
```

I think this has something to do with the way I'm dealing with `sign_out`, if so how can I test controllers that are logged out? Or maybe I should give up and do this with Capybara?

Comment: Have you added the `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller` line as suggested in that page?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Yes, as above I can get `sign_in` to work fine but not `sign_out`...